# How to hit a breakpoint in application while running UI test in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing, xcode10

We have an iOS application for which we have written XCUI tests.
We need to debug the iOS application while the test is running to capture some data. But breakpoints set in the application are never hit. Only the breakpoints in the test target gets hit.
Is it not possible to debug the application while the ui tests are running it?
Any solution?

Thanks,
Reshma

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if this works with XCUI tests, but you might be able to connect xcode to the correct process while the tests are running via `Debug -> Attach to Process -> [Your app's process name]`.

Comment: I can see that breakpoint is working for both UITest & Code as well. Did you try to run a test & try to record it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select your test scheme and go to Edit Scheme...

Select 'Test' in the sidebar and in the 'Info' category check the 'Debug executable' option.

When you run the tests in that scheme, breakpoints in both the test target and the app under test will be hit.